# Python smtplib: Why is the connection refused?

Tags: python, email, smtp, send, connection

So, in the Python interpreter, I do this (and only this):

```
>>> import smtplib
>>> s=smtplib.SMTP("localhost")
```

And this is what I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/usr/lib/python3.4/smtplib.py", line 242, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.4/smtplib.py", line 321, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.4/smtplib.py", line 292, in _get_socket
    self.source_address)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line 509, in create_connection
    raise err
    File "/usr/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line 500, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to why am I getting this error? (That's my question.) It's not supposed to do that from what I understand. Tell me if I'm wrong.

I'm using Xubuntu 14.04. If you need more information, please ask. I don't know of anything else I can tell you, off-hand.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have Mail server on your local computer ?

Comment: No. (See my comment to iandouglas's answer that I just posted.)

Comment: Now I see - You can use `smtplib` to send mails using your account on mail server like `gmail.com` or others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SMTPlib is going to try to connect to an SMTP service, usually running on port 25, though it can run on various other ports. Sounds like maybe you need to install sendmail, postfix, or something of that nature.

Comment: Ah. I thought you could use it in place of something like postfix. So, it requires one of them, it seems. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Try starting a server in another terminal on you machine by running,

```
python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025
```

Then in the first terminal or script you can say,

```
import smtplib
s = smtplib.SMTP( "localhost", 1025 )
```